# Riddle: What did they start?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> It all started with a group of four. 
>  Their legacy inheritors
>   compete round the clock for the annual prize.
>  People say the
>   lovely head has got style.
>  Fluffy the pet can be found in the
>   belly.
>  Even the Riddle that shan't be spoken of, had been
>   here.
>  What did the four start?

**Hint 1**:

> Debts can also be settled in the "moneytrench".

**Hint 2**:

> It is me,the famous "Swineblemishes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must surely be

> Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, from J K Rowling's "Harry Potter" books.

It all started with a group of four.

> The founders: Godric Gryffindor, Helga Hufflepuff, Rowena Ravenclaw, and Salazar Slytherin.

Their legacy inheritors compete round the clock for the annual prize.

> The four houses that bear their names.

People say the lovely head has got style.

> Not sure exactly why "lovely", but at least one character says in so many words that Albus Dumbledore "has style".

Fluffy the pet can be found in the belly.

> Hagrid's three-headed dog, guarding the entrance to the place where the Philosopher's Stone is hidden in the first book.

Even the Riddle that shan't be spoken of, had been here.

> Tom Marvolo Riddle, also known as Lord Voldemort, also known as "He who must not be named".

What did the four start?

> The school.

Hints:

> Not sure right now what the first one is about. [EDITED to add: ffao points out in comments that this must be about Quid-ditch.] The second one is just a slightly cryptic way of telling us the answer: swine=hog, blemishes=warts.

Comment: Re hint 1: I heard in your land people might use "quid" to refer to money?

Comment: ah, yeah, I guess so. Not terribly convinced by "Debts can also be settled" there, but never mind.

Comment: @ffao, Gareth McCaughan kudos to you both. about the hint "they beat each other black and blue in the matches" so I added it. You solved my first ever puzzle question pretty quickly, do you have any suggestions that would have made it harder?

Comment: @kolshe You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of how others craft and present their puzzles. One note about hints - they are generally best left until some time has passed with no progress on the puzzle, rather than given right away, as they can give away far too much about the puzzle up front.  Thanks for your puzzle, and  hope your next puzzle sees great success!